# HTML-5 Audio Analyser - Incorrect Frequencies Shown?

Tags: firefox, audio, html5-audio, getusermedia

While playing around with the createAnalyser part of HTML audio, I noticed discrepancies between what is shown in the bar graphs and the real audio frequencies.

While the 5K test tone (generated via audacity) shows a close match,

[image: 5K Test tone]

the 10K is way off.

[image: 10K Test tone]

Smoothing doesn't seem to have any effect. The pink-noise curve is equally questionable.

[image: Pink Noise]

The drop off at around 12Khz is not correct.

The sampling frequency is 44100 with the fftSize set to 128.

I was wondering, if anybody else has made experiences like this. May very well be the internal sound system or, well, incorrect rounding on Firefox's part.

Comment: Well, well. Problem (not) solved. Turns out, browsers can't give good results while analyzing real time audio. I tested my functions against audio data loaded as file and it worked ok. I took another implementation of a frequency analyzer that worked great with loaded data and patched it to work with a real time recording and it showed the same errors.  Firefox can only go up to 10Khz, Chrome makes it to about 14 Khz - both on CentOs.

Answer (score 0):

Frequency analysis doesn't work well on life recordings. See my comment above.